# ideally accurate measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem

In the address below
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics
it's written:

> *For pedagogic reasons, the measurement [in quantum mechanics] is usually assumed to be ideally accurate.*
>   What's the meaning?

Comment: all of our measurements are subject to some margin of error

Comment: Is it saying quantum principles are based on this ideal assumption? Like when the state collapses into an eigenstate due to measurement.

Comment: I am open to correction on this, but to me it's nothing to do with wavefunction collapse.  it's more like doing dynamics problems (or thermodynamics and using ideal gases) and ignoring air resistance, because if they were to include that, the problem would be too messy.  To me the quote above just means, "we will ignore the fact that we can't actually measure things precisely", so just assume we can while we teach you this.

Comment: ideally accurate should mean something like "all errors eliminated but quantum uncertainty". That is grad student performing experiment is sober and temperature in room is exactly 24C and constant. And we are in spherical vacuum.

Comment: It simply means that you won't learn anything about quantum mechanics from putting a layer of error calculation on top of real experiments. Once you enter the real world, of course, that simplification is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any great meaning to this statement - I think the author(s) are indicating how measurement is treated in QM formalism, rather than any practical issues introduced by measuring such systems.

Because this is dangerously close to the topic of the [uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) / [observer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)), it's worth stating that quantum uncertainty *is not* a result of a measurement process, but rather intrinsic to [conjugate variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables).  Historically, this has been mistaken many times.